# How to make 2 div inside an outer div inline?

Tags: html, css

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vr2k23s1/) has the code that I've implemented.
I have a `div` which contains 2 `div` that should be inline.

The outermost div must be `100%` in `width` and each inner `div`'s must have `width:50%`. The problem is the inner `div` stack on top of each other. If I change `width` of either one to `49%`, then they're `inline`, but there seems to be some sort of padding from bottom. 

 
I tried `float:left`on both the inner `div` and that made the inner `div`'s inline but then the outer `div`'s height won't adjust automatically according to height of inner `div`'s. How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```css
.outer {
  background-color: green;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.box-one {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.box-two {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box-one"></div><div class="box-two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.outer {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
}

.box-one {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 179px;
  float: left;
}

.box-two {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 179px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Please check the link I've provided again, I accidentally linked it to some other fiddle before.

Comment: hi Sidsec use this css

Answer (score 1):

Give both `first` and `second` div `width:50%`

Check [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/qMQL5/855/)

**Update:**

Just remove `display: inline-block;` from both divs [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vr2k23s1/1/)

Comment: Please check the link I've provided again, I accidentally linked it to some other fiddle before.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the container `overflow:hidden` to quickly contain floated elements

```
 #container {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #ffcc33;
   margin: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
  }

 #first {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: blue;
 }
 #second {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: green;
 }
```

Here is the fixed [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qMQL5/856/).

Otherwise i'd recommend looking into [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Comment: Please check the link I've provided again, I accidentally linked it to some other fiddle before.

Comment: The same solution applies just with different class names insted of id's, unless i am misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your two divs don't fit is that `inline-block` respects whitespace. You have a carriage return between `.box-one` and `.box-two`. This is rendered as a space character between the blocks.

You have four options which I have illustrated in this codepen http://codepen.io/magpie/pen/QwzNYe:

1: If you wish to use `display: inline-block`, you can either set `font-size: 0` on the `.outer` div and reset it for the child divs. Then the 'space' will literally take up zero pixels in width and everything will fit. Obviously, if the `.outer` div will contain text, this won't work. The other alternative is simply to remove the carriage return between the child divs as Danield has shown.

2: You can use floats but the `.outer` div will collapse in height. To counter this, apply a clearfix or simply `overflow: hidden` to `.outer`

3: You can use a fake table layout by applying `display: table` to `.outer` and `display: table-cell` to the children. You will need to specify the 100% width of the `.outer` div.

4: Most simple of all is to use flexbox. Make the `.outer` div `display: flex` and voila! Support is pretty good these days: check http://caniuse.com for support and necessary vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the white-space between the child elements. (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements))

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/vr2k23s1/3/)

```css
.outer {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
.box-one {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box-two {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box-one"></div><div class="box-two"></div>
</div>
```